# Return a list of objects as json in mvc 4 vb.net

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to return the below json :

```
 [
{
    "tag": "test",
    "values": [
        {
            "en": "english text",
            "ar": "arabic text"
        },
        {
            "en": "english text",
            "ar": "arabic text"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tag": "test2",
    "values": [
        {
            "en": "english text",
            "ar": "arabic text"
        },
        {
            "en": "english text",
            "ar": "arabic text"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

i need to return the above json in mvc4.net so i tried creating the below classes :

```
 Public Class AppLabels
    Public Property labels As New labelsTag()
End Class

Public Class labelsTag
    Public Property tag As String = ""
    Public Property values As DataTable
End Class
```

but i'm not being able to set a list of the `labelsTag` in other words i'm not able to write :

```
   labels.labels(0).tag_name = "test"
   labels.labels(0).values = datatable1
```

because `labels.labels` is not being taken as an array...

any help plz..

Comment: `values` needs to be a collection of an object containing properties `en` and `ar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a class for this node :

```
 {
   "en": "english text",
   "ar": "arabic text"
 }
```

The Class Will be :

```
Public Class value

    Public en As String

    Public ar As String
End Class
```

Then this json part

```
 {
        "tag": "test",
        "values": [
            {
                "en": "english text",
                "ar": "arabic text"
            },
            {
                "en": "english text",
                "ar": "arabic text"
            }
        ]
    }
```

will be represented by :

```
Public Class Smalljson

    Public tag As String

    Public values As List(Of value)
End Class
```

And Finaly the last class will be :

```
    Public Class finaljson

       Public json As List(Of Smalljson)
    End Class
```

example how to use :

```
 Dim json As finaljson = New finaljson
 Dim j As Integer = 0
 Do While (j < 2)
    Dim sj As Smalljson = New Smalljson
    sj.tag = ("test" + j)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < 2)
        Dim v As value = New value
        v.en = ("english text" + i)
        v.ar = ("arabic text" + i)
        sj.values.Add(v)
        i = (i + 1)
    Loop
    json.Add(sj)
    j = (j + 1)
Loop
```

NB : I didnt Test the code but i guess it should work perfectly

Cheers !